# Call my BraodcastReceiver using AlarmManager? [DONE]

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have to call my BroadcastReceiver through AlaramManager.

for this what I did , is not working:

**AlarmActivity.java**

```
public class AlarmActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 50);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

**Edit : Solution**

        //Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, MyService.class);
        //PendingIntent  pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(AlarmActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
        //alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        //alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

     AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent intent1 = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, MyService.class);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent =   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, 0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**MyService.java**

```
public class MyService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            Log.e("Broadcast", "Done");
    }
}
```

`Also give alarm permission and receiver`

**This is what I used but is not working . Can you tell what i missed ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
 AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Scheduling.this, Feedback.class);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent =   PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Scheduling.this, 0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), 86400000, pendingIntent);
```

add receiver in menifest

Comment: <receiver android:name=".MyService"/ > , I pass this .  What about this ?

Comment: nothing it defines when phone re-boot it will start automatically

Comment: Done :) there is no receiver problem , actually pendingIntent is the problem